# Clarify file/dir list to include in duply profile

Tags: duplicity, duplicity-backup

I have defined `/tmp/` as my source directory. I want to backup only `in1/` and `in2/` subfolders from it. What lines do I need in profile's `exclude` file?

```
/tmp/a
├── in1
│   └── in.txt
├── in2
│   └── in.txt
└── out.txt
```

According to [duplicity man](https://linux.die.net/man/1/duplicity) page's `dir/foo` example, I tried:

```
+ in1/
+ in2/
- **
```

But that did not work and I got error as:

```
Reading globbing filelist /path/to/duply_profile/exclude
Fatal Error: The file specification
    in1/
cannot match any files in the base directory
    /tmp
Useful file specifications begin with the base directory or some
pattern (such as '**') which matches the base directory.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

better use up-to-date man page from duplicity's website https://duplicity.us/stable/duplicity.1.html#file-selection

not sure why the example relative paths is in there, but as the error states you will need something along the lines

```
+ /tmp/in1/
+ /tmp/in2/
- **
```

feel free to post a bug ticket on https://gitlab.com/duplicity/duplicity/-/issues so maybe someday some kind soul would make it work with relative paths.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, your solution will surely work. I also posted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I figured that the following specification work:

```
+ **in1/
+ **in2/
- **
```

Comment: yeah, well. that'd work but it'd include any folder ending in "in1" or "in2". depending on your source data that might not be what you want :)